# React Hook + Context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am fairly new to React Hooks and context api. I am trying to create a global state management within react (no redux) but I am running into this error.

`TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

I just started this project and just trying to set up a shopping cart (which will use the global CartItem to keep track of total items)

GlobalStates.jsx (My global state manager file)

```
import React from 'react';

export const CartContext = React.createContext(0)

const GlobalContextWrapper = (props) => {
    const [cartItem,incCartItem] = React.useState(0);
    return(
        <CartContext.Provider value={[cartItem,incCartItem]}>
            {props.children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default GlobalContextWrapper
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import GlobalContextWrapper from "./GlobalStates.jsx"

import Test from "./Test.jsx"

const Main = () => {
    return(
      <GlobalContextWrapper>
        <Test/>
      </GlobalContextWrapper>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Test.jsx (the file which is trying to access the context global states)

```
import React from 'react';
import CartContext from "./GlobalStates"

const Test = () => {
    const [cartItem,incCartItem] = React.useContext(CartContext)
    return(
        <h1>The cart total is {cartItem}</h1>
    )
}

export default Test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works just fine, but in Test you need to import the context correctly: `import {CartContext} from "./GlobalStates"`

```js
const CartContext = React.createContext(0);

const GlobalContextWrapper = (props) => {
  const [cartItem, incCartItem] = React.useState(0);
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={[cartItem, incCartItem]}>
      {props.children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
const Test = () => {
  const [cartItem, incCartItem] = React.useContext(
    CartContext
  );
  return <h1>The cart total is {cartItem}</h1>;
};

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <GlobalContextWrapper>
      <Test />
    </GlobalContextWrapper>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```